# Case Statements / Unix Scripting

Tags: loops, unix, while-loop, case

So basically i have a script that add/delete a number on a file

1. user will choose which file he/she want to delete a number
2. i already make some error handling
3. but when i am running the script it says "./zz.sh: line 124: syntax error near unexpected token `;;' ./zz.sh: line 124:`
       ;;'"
4. this error shows uppon choosing which file to edit

Here's my script

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

StagingDir="/qual/qms2ai3/ai/ELILY/villegastest/staging"
OldDir="/qual/qms2ai3/ai/ELILY/villegastest/old"
HomeDir="/qual/qms2ai3/ai/ELILY/villegastest"
sysConn=`cd /qual/qms2ai3/ai/ELILY/villegastest/ | ls FDW856.cntl`
sysConn2=`ls -lrt FDW810.cntl`
xmlConn=`ls -lrt XML810.cntl`
xmlConn2=`ls -lrt XML856.cntl`
wawfConn=`ls -lrt WAWF856.cntl`
chkDir=`pwd`
#EntSysUser=`goto entsys`
FileDate=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
GREEN="\e[1;32;40m"
RESET="\033[0m"

echo ""
echo "  ###########################################################"
echo "  #                                                         #"
echo "  #                                                         #"
echo "  #                 System Connect Setup                    #"
echo "  #                                                         #"
echo "  #                                                         #"
echo "  ###########################################################"
echo ""
echo  "         1)   System Connect ( FDW856 ) "
echo  "         2)   System Connect ( FDW810 ) "
echo  "         3)   XML ( XML810 ) "
echo  "         4)   XML ( XML8856 ) "
echo  "         5)   WAWF 856 ( WAWF856 ) "
echo  "         0)   Exit"
echo ""


read -p "Where do you wish to add/delete the R3 number in the control file? " LocCtrlFile

Counter()
{
count=`echo -e "$CtrlNumber\c" | wc -m`
diff=`expr 10 - $count`

if [ $diff -gt 0 ]; then
while [ $diff -gt 0 ]
do
echo -n "0"
diff=`expr $diff - 1`
done
echo -n "$CtrlNumber"
echo ""
fi
}


case ${LocCtrlFile} in

        "1")

                echo "You choose 1) System Connect ( FDW* )."
                echo -e "File(s) for System Connect: $GREEN${sysConn}$RESET"
                echo "Chaging to EntSys User.."
                #$EntSysUser
                sleep 1
                echo -e "Current directory during the backup: $GREEN${chkDir}$RESET"

                cd ${HomeDir}
                echo -e "Creating a copy of the original file in $GREEN~/staging directory..$RESET"
                cp -pf ${HomeDir}/${sysConn} ${StagingDir}
                sleep 1
                echo -e "Done creating a copy of the original file in $GREEN~/staging directory..$RESET"
                echo -e "Creating a backup of the control file in $GREEN~/old directory..$RESET"
                cp -pf ${HomeDir}/${sysConn} ${OldDir}/${sysConn}.${FileDate}
                sleep 1
                echo -e "Backup done at $GREEN~/old directory..$RESET"

                read -p "Do you wish to ADD or DEL the R3 number in the control file ${sysConnFile} (ADD/DEL)?: " choiceDesc
                finDesc=`echo "${choiceDesc}" | awk '{print toupper($1)}'`
                        case $finDesc in

                                        "ADD")
                                                while :
                                                do
                                                while :
                                                        do
                                                        read -p "Please enter the R3 number(should be 10char): " CtrlNumber
                                                           count2=`echo -e "$CtrlNumber\c" | wc -m`
                                                           if [ $count2 -eq 10 ]   ;
                                                           then
                                                           CtrlNumber=$CtrlNumber
                                                           break;
                                                           elif [ $count2 -lt 10 ] ;
                                                           then
                                                           CtrlNumber=$(Counter)
                                                           break;
                                                           elif [ $count2 -gt 10 ] ;
                                                                then
                                                        echo "Control number is more than 10"
                                                        CtrlNumber=$CtrlNumber
                                                           fi
                                                        done

                                                        checkNum=$(grep -w $CtrlNumber $sysConn | wc -l)

                                                        if [ $checkNum -ge 1 ] ;

                                                        then
                                                             echo "${CtrlNumber} already exist at ${sysConn}."
                                                       else
                                                                        echo  "Your new Control Number is: $GREEN${CtrlNumber}$RESET"
                                                                        printf "${CtrlNumber}" >> ${StagingDir}/${sysConn}
                                                                        sort -u ${StagingDir}/${sysConn} >> ${StagingDir}/${sysConn}.srt
                                                                        mv -f ${StagingDir}/${sysConn}.srt ${StagingDir}/${sysConn}
                                                                        cp -pf ${StagingDir}/${sysConn} ${HomeDir}

                                                                        echo "Diff of Entsys and ~/staging"
                                                                        #Cmp entsys and ~/staging version
                                                                        diff ${HomeDir}/${sysConn} ${StagingDir}/${sysConn}
                                                                        echo "Diff of Entsys and ~/old"
                                                                        #Cmp entsys version and ~/old
                                                                        diff ${HomeDir}/${sysConn} ${OldDir}/${sysConn}.${FileDate}
                                                                        exit 0
                                                        fi
                                        ;;

                                    "DEL")
                                                     read -p "Please enter the R3 number(should be 10char): " CtrlNumber
                                                     echo "Deleting Control Number: $GREEN${CtrlNumber}$RESET"

                                                     checkNum=$(grep -w $CtrlNumber $sysConn | wc -l)

                                                        if [ $checkNum -ge 1 ] ;

                                                        then

                                                          store=`grep -v "$CtrlNumber" $sysConn`
                                                          echo "${store}" > ${StagingDir}/${sysConn}
                                                          sort -u ${StagingDir}/${sysConn} >>  ${StagingDir}/${sysConn}.srt
                                                          mv -f ${StagingDir}/${sysConn}.srt ${StagingDir}/${sysConn}
                                                          cp -pf ${StagingDir}/${sysConn} ${HomeDir}

                                                          echo "Diff of Entsys and ~/staging"
                                                          #Cmp entsys and ~/staging version
                                                          diff ${HomeDir}/${sysConn} ${StagingDir}/${sysConn}

                                                          echo "Diff of Entsys and ~/old"
                                                          #Cmp entsys version and ~/old
                                                          diff ${HomeDir}/${sysConn} ${OldDir}/${sysConn}.${FileDate}

                                                        else

                                                             echo "${CtrlNumber} doesn't exist."

                                                        fi

                                    ;;

                                                                        "*")
                                                                        echo "Please choose ADD or DEL only"
                                                                        ;;

                                                                done
                        esac
                esac
```

Whats seems to be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Remove "done" from line 162 and put it in line 124 and then try.

Comment: As above, you have 2 while loops in ADD but only a single done :)

Comment: Hi VIPI KUMAR, thank you! i miss seen that part